# bash script - unable to set variable with double quotes in value

Tags: bash, shell, unix, escaping, quoting

Need help in fixing this bash script to set a variable with a value including double quotes. Somehow I am defining this incorrectly as my values `foo` and `bar` are not enclosed in double quotes as needed.

My script thus far:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
set -e
set -x

host='127.0.0.1'
db='mydev'
_account="foo"
_profile="bar"
_version=$1
_mongo=$(which mongo);

exp="db.profile_versions_20170420.find({account:${_account}, profile:${_profile}, version:${_version}}).pretty();";
${_mongo} ${host}/${db} --eval "$exp"

set +x
```

Output shows:

```
+ host=127.0.0.1
+ db=mydev
+ _account=foo
+ _profile=bar
+ _version=201704112004
++ which mongo
+ _mongo=/usr/local/bin/mongo
+ exp='db.profile_versions_20170420.find({account:foo, profile:bar, version:201704112004}).pretty();'
+ /usr/local/bin/mongo 127.0.0.1/mydev --eval 'db.profile_versions_20170420.find({account:foo, profile:bar, version:201704112004}).pretty();'
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.4
connecting to: 127.0.0.1/mydev
2017-04-22T15:32:55.012-0700 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: foo is not defined :
@(shell eval):1:36
```

What i need is `account:"foo"`, `profile:"bar"` to be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: `export` has a precise meaning in a shell script, and I see no evidence that any variables in this script are being exported.

Comment: @noober, btw, it's **much** more efficient to just run `mongo`, not to run `_mongo=$(which mongo)` and then invoke `"$_mongo"`. The latter spawns a subshell and then invokes an external process to do the lookup -- either of those steps is *individually* more expensive than just doing the PATH lookup internal to the shell itself.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy- duly noted. Will keep this more simple.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In bash (and other POSIX shells), the following 2 states are equivalent:

```
_account=foo
_account="foo"
```

What you want to do is to preserve the quotations, therefore you can do the following:

```
_account='"foo"'
```

Comment: Not just bash, but baseline POSIX sh as well (thus, all shells in the family).

Comment: thank you all for your help. Adding the single quotes around the double quotes worked.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy - I've amended my answer to include this.

Comment: There's little reason to include the quotes in the value of the variables `_account` and `_profile`; it's the value of `exp` that needs the quotes.

Comment: The quotes will be contained within the variable, so when the variable is expanded within `exp` then the quotes which are attached to `_account` would also be included.

Answer (score 7):

Since part of what you're doing here is forming JSON, consider using `jq` -- which will **guarantee** that it's well-formed, no matter what the values are.

```
host='127.0.0.1'
db='mydev'
_account="foo"
_profile="bar"
_version=$1

json=$(jq -n --arg account "$_account" --arg profile "$_profile" --arg version "$_version" \
  '{$account, $profile, version: $version | tonumber}')

exp="db.profile_versions_20170420.find($json).pretty();"
mongo "${host}/${db}" --eval "$exp"
```

This makes `jq` responsible for adding literal quotes where appropriate, and will avoid attempted injection attacks (for instance, via a version passed in `$1` containing something like `1, "other_argument": "malicious_value"`), by replacing any literal `"` in a string with `\"`; a literal newline with `\n`, etc -- or, with the `| tonumber` conversion, failing outright with any non-numeric value.

---

Note that some of the syntax above requires jq 1.5 -- if you have 1.4 or prior, you'll want to write `{account: $account, profile: $profile}` instead of being able to write `{$account, $profile}` with the key names inferred from the variable names.

Comment: Nice answer as well. Definitely makes this more robust. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

When you need to use double quotes inside a double quoted string, escape them with backslashes:

```
$ foo="acount:\"foo\"" sh -c 'echo $foo'
  acount:"foo"
```

Answer (score 4):

I needed to enquote something already in a variable and stick that in a variable. Expanding on [Robert Seaman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43565503), I found this worked:

```
VAR='"'$1'"'
```

(single quote, double quote, single quote,
 variable,
single quote, double quote, single quote)